# WP_Query use for a filter with multiple Taxonomies and Terms

Tags: php, wp-query, custom-taxonomy, terms, advanced-taxonomy-queries

So, what I'm trying to do, is to make an ajax filter, this is the portion of the filter code that builds the $args based on the data that came from the filter form, and afterwards (not in this code) it gives the results of the query.

I have 3 custom taxonomies (and their functionality from form):
- type_emp (one option comes from form)
- status_emp (ONE OR MORE options comes from form)
- city_emp (one option comes from form)

Thing is: **I'm not able to use them in the WP_Query as filters, since they will match the post even if it doesn't have all the terms.**

#### Example

type_emp is 1
status_emp is null
city_emp is 2

#### It will return posts:

(type_emp / status_emp / city_emp)
post 1 ( 1 / 2 / 3)
post 2 ( 2 / 1, 4 / 2)
post 3 ( 1 / 4 / 2)

As you can see, post 3 should be the only one returned, since he has all the parameters. **Is there a way to restrict the query like that**?
Also, I need to match status_emp more than once, with sometimes multiple terms, down in the code, I explode the string to make an array and put it as terms in a tax query. **How to I match posts that have at least one of them**?

```php
$args = array(
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'post_status' => 'publish'
);

if ( isset( $_POST['typefilter'] ) && $_POST['typefilter'] !== '' ) {
    $args['post_type'] = 'post_type_x';
    $args['tax_query'] = array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'type_emp',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => $_POST['typefilter']
        )
    );
}

if ( $_POST['typefilter'] == '') {
    $args['post_type'] = 'post_type_x';
}

// If two or more options are selected they are sorted below
$query  = explode('&', file_get_contents("php://input"));
$params = array();

foreach( $query as $param )
{
  list($name, $value) = explode('=', $param, 2);
  $params[urldecode($name)][] = urldecode($value);
}

if( isset( $params['statusfilter'] ) && $_POST['statusfilter'] !== '' ) {
    $args['tax_query'] .= array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'status_emp',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => $params['statusfilter']
        )
    );
}

// for taxonomies / categories
if( isset( $_POST['cityfilter'] ) && $_POST['cityfilter'] !== '') {
    $args['tax_query'] .= array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'city_emp',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => $_POST['cityfilter']
        )
    );
}
$query = new WP_Query($args);
```

Sorry if my question is a bit confuse, but I tried to be the most clear possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this way:

```
$args = array(
    'orderby'     => 'date',
    'order'       => 'DESC',
    'post_status' => 'publish'
);

if ( isset( $_POST['typefilter'] ) && $_POST['typefilter'] !== '' ) {
    $args['post_type']                = 'post_type_x';
    $args['tax_query'][0]['taxonomy'] = 'type_emp';
    $args['tax_query'][0]['field']    = 'id';
    $args['tax_query'][0]['terms']    = $_POST['typefilter'];
    $args['tax_query'][0]['operator'] = 'IN';
}

if ( $_POST['typefilter'] == '') {
    $args['post_type'] = 'post_type_x';
}

// If two or more options are selected they are sorted below
$query  = explode('&', file_get_contents("php://input"));
$params = array();

foreach( $query as $param )
{
  list($name, $value) = explode('=', $param, 2);
  $params[urldecode($name)][] = urldecode($value);
}

if( isset( $params['statusfilter'] ) && $_POST['statusfilter'] !== '' ) {
    $args['tax_query'][1]['taxonomy'] = 'status_emp';
    $args['tax_query'][1]['field']    = 'id';
    $args['tax_query'][1]['terms']    = $params['statusfilter'];
    $args['tax_query'][1]['operator'] = 'IN';
}

// for taxonomies / categories
if( isset( $_POST['cityfilter'] ) && $_POST['cityfilter'] !== '') {
    $args['tax_query'][2]['taxonomy'] = 'city_emp';
    $args['tax_query'][2]['field']    = 'id';
    $args['tax_query'][2]['terms']    = $_POST['cityfilter'];
    $args['tax_query'][2]['operator'] = 'IN';
}

$query = new WP_Query($args);
```

I haven't tested it but theoretically it should work :), tell me if it works or if you need more help

Comment: Hey @benny-ben, thanks for the answer, actually I gave it more time and the solution came to me. You answer should still work, just as the solution I did. Mine is different.
The problem was that I was appending arrays on the 'tax_query' value, but not listing them with commas, so the value was passed just as `"ArrayArray"` and not as each arrays listed. What I did was build an array at each one, with a variable, and in the end, build the `$args['tax_query']` like this: `$args['tax_query'] = array($type, $status, $city);` So it works now :D